# nuxt-link to open a page in the parent of a nuxt-child

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

I'm using a **NuxtJS pages** setup similar to this:

```
./pages/about.vue
./pages/phones/index.vue
./pages/phones/details.vue
./pages/phones.vue
```

Inside the `./pages/phones.vue` -file I'm using a `<nuxt-child />` component to render the `./pages/phones/index.vue` and `./pages/phones/details.vue` inside of it. Like so:

File: `./pages/phones.vue`:

```html
<nuxt-child />
```

Inside the `./pages/phones/details.vue` -page I have a link that needs to open the `./pages/about.vue` in the **"parent"** `<Nuxt />` (the normal NuxtJS router-view) **NOT the `<nuxt-child />`** router view.

This is similar to how old-school iframes can open a URL in their parent by using `target="_parent"` attribute.

But the nuxt-link "about" (that links to `./pages/about.vue` -page) is still opening in the nuxt-child (router-view).

I think their should be some kind of `target` property on the `<nuxt-link>` -component:

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'about', target: '_parent' }">About</nuxt-link>
```

**NOTE: The above example doesn't work. I'm looking for something like this.**

I've searched the web; but, how do you open a link from within a `<nuxt-child />` into the parent `<Nuxt />` (router) view?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a custom `<nuxt/>` component as `<custom-nuxt/>` like below:

```js
<template>
    <main>
        <transition
            mode="out-in"
            name="page"/>
            <router-view v-if="!nuxt.err"/>
            <error-view :error="nuxt.err" v-else/>
        </transition>
    </main>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
import Vue from 'vue';
import ErrorView from '@/layouts/error';
export default{
    components: {
        ErrorView
    },
    beforeCreate () {
        Vue.util.defineReactive(this, 'nuxt', this.$root.$options.nuxt);
    }
}
</script>
```

use this instead of `<nuxt/>`, and replace `<nuxt-link/>` with `<router-link/>`, code just like what you did in a SPA-Vue project. Don't forget to code your own `<error-view/>`